# sync 2 machines using wget

Tags: linux, backup, bash-scripting

I have a machine in my LAN that runs *Ubuntu* and I have full access in it.

There is another PC on the Internet that has a public IP eg `3.3.3.3` and it servers as **https server** and access to it is by username and password.

At the moment I'm logging to the *ubuntu* and using `wget` to get folders that I want.

I would like to automate the boring stuff and every 1 hour to check if the server has new content compared to the ubuntu's `/var/www/html/A` and `/var/www/html/B` local folders.

If it has different content, then download the new content and delete the old ones in the corresponding folder.

If not then do nothing until next run.

It is a one way sync. is there any script that could do the job, please?

Comment: wget -m is what you need.

Comment: could you be a bit more descriptive please?

Comment: use `man wget` to read the wget manual - you're looking for the mirror option, it'll keep a local copy of the website, and only updates parts which have changed since the last time you ran it.

Comment: at the moment i have wget -N --no-check-certificate --user atux password null -r -np https://3.3.3.3/xxx -P /var/www/html but when i go to the local server i see /var/www/html/3.3.3.3 which is the remote IP. how can i get rid of the 3.3.3.3 from my local folder?